# How can I forward SSH connections on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, vpn

I need to connect to an SSH server that resides inside a local network. I can connect to the network over VPN, whose client is available for Windows only.

I have a virtual Windows 10 computer running the VPN client. The computer can connect to the SSH server when the VPN software is connected. Windows can't share the VPN client's connection directly.

I'd like to connect to the SSH server using my host machine. Is there a Windows program that can forward inbound SSH connections to a remote machine? If not is there another way to achieve this?

So in short, I need to connect to an SSH server via a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bridged network adapter to your VM ... the IP in the same network as your Host pc .. on the VM, set-up Internet Connection Sharing for the VPN connected "nic", set a static route on your host pc, for the SSH server you want to reach, with a gateway / next hop, of the IP address of the Bridged Interface of the VM.

Sample with psuedo IP's:

```
Host PC 192.168.1.101
VM Bridged Interface 192.168.1.102
VM Interface w/VPN 192.168.10.10
```

SSH server you're trying to reach: 192.168.125.125

route add host 192.168.125.125 GW 192.168.1.102

Your Real Host PC .. should be able to ping 192.168.1.102 (so should others on your network)

Comment: Connection sharing is not allowed on the VPN adapter. It can not be selected as a shared connection.